# Вывод данных из бд в виде: [Ljava.lang.Object; @xxxxx как исправить?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, listview, android-studio

Есть база данных, из которой осуществляется вывод в List View. Вместо данных выводятся строки непонятных символов. Что именно здесь не так? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

//Helper

```
public class Helper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static final String DBName ="BookD.sqlite";
private static final int DBV=1;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public Helper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DBName,null,DBV);
}


public Helper open() throws SQLiteException {
    db =getWritableDatabase();

    return this;  }

public ArrayList<Object[]> geData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[]columns=new String[]{"id","title","author"};
    Cursor c =db.query("books", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<Object[]> array = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {

            Object[] obj =new Object[3];

            obj[0]=c.getInt(0);
            obj[1]=c.getString(1);
           obj[2]=c.getString(2);
            array.add(obj);

        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }return array;
}}
```

//MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Helper helper= new Helper(getApplicationContext());


    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMe);
    Helper info = new Helper(this);
    info.open();

    ArrayList<Object[]> array = info.geData();
    info.close();
   lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object[]>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter в пункт списка пишет то, что возвращает метод `toString()`, класса заключенного в угловые скобки, в вашем случае `Object[]`. 
Я бы написал класс, переопределил бы метод `toString()` в зависимости от того, что нужно видеть в списке и сунул бы адаптеру.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " " +  title + " " + author;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String autor) {
        this.author = autor;
    }
}
```

---

Дальше использовать так:

```
public ArrayList<SomeClass> geData() {
    String[]columns=new String[]{"id","title","author"};
    Cursor c =db.query("books", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<SomeClass> array = new ArrayList<>();
    while (c.moveToNext());
            SomeClass someclass =new SomeClass();

            someclass.setId(c.getInt(0);
            someclass.setTitle(c.getString(1));
            someclass.setAuthor(c.getString(2));
            array.add(someclass);
        } 

    }return array;
}}
```

---

```
 ArrayList<SomeClass> array = info.geData();
 info.close();
 lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<SomeClass>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
```